# Split Array if comma is found

Tags: powershell

```
$FruitArray[0] = "Banana, Orange, Peach, Mangoes"
$FruitArray[1] = "Apple, Banana"
$FruitArray[2] = "Peach"
$FruitArray[3] = "Mangoes"
```

How to split the array items to get the following results?

```
$FruitArray[0] = "Banana"
$FruitArray[1] = "Orange"
$FruitArray[2] = "Peach" 
$FruitArray[3] = "Mangoes"
$FruitArray[4] = "Apple"
$FruitArray[5] = "Banana"
$FruitArray[6] = "Peach"
$FruitArray[7] = "Mangoes"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the array elements at commas and assign the result back to the variable.

```
$FruitArray = $FruitArray -split ',\s*'
```